# Save HTML, CSS + Images for offline usage

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c, offline

My iOS app needs to work completely offline if the user downloads all the data. Some views are mobile websites, so all I do when a user views a website online is download the URL from the database and display that in a UIWebView.
However when the user decides to download all the data for offline usage I need to display that webpage offline.

I tried

```
NSData *myPagedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.nl/"]];
```

and then display that data in an UIWebView

```
[_webView loadData:myPagedata MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

But that doesnt save CSS and images.

I also found out that [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest) can do this but thats a dead project. Does anybody know how I can display a webpage offline with CSS and images?

Comment: I think this can be done with AFNetworking 2's [UIWebView category](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.2/Categories/UIWebView+AFNetworking.html) in combination with [NSURLCache](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/) but I'm not 100% so I didn't want to write it as an answer

Comment: Will check this out right now and post my results here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at AFCache. https://github.com/artifacts/AFCache

I have not tried this library but it looks promising.